# How to change Y Axis Min/Max scale values using c#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I'm trying to change the **Y Axis Scale** limits of `Excel Chart` using `C#` , the following code works fine on `X-axis` but struggling to change this to Y-axis.

```
 Excel.Axis ax = chartPage_1.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlCategory, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary) as Excel.Axis;
 ax.MinimumScale = 0.3;
```

any help or suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `XlAxisType.xlCategory`, use `XlAxisType.xlValue`

Here's the code I'm using:

```
myChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlValue).MinimumScale = MIN_SCALE;
```

Could be that different chart types will/won't work with this.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, just tried your bit & I get the following error: `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component`.

Comment: sorry, my mistake I forgot to change the `XlAxisGroup.xlSecondary` back to `XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary`. Worked like a gem, Thanks a lot...:)

Comment: It worked for me. can you please tell me how can I change the value of **Horizontal Axis**??
Because right now it is simply 1,2,3,4,5.... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if you want to change the horizontal axis, you must use:

```
myChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory).MinimumScale = MIN_SCALE;
myChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory).MaximumScale = MAX_SCALE;
myChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory).MajorUnit = MAJOR_UNIT;
```

Each of them corresponds for some configuration in Excel.
**xlCategory = Horizontal axis** and
**xlValue = Vertical axis**